# AJAX POST in Codeigniter not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-2

I have the following code in Codeigniter:

Controller (users.php):

```
         public function ajaxform()
              {
               $this->load->helper('url');
               $this->load->view('users/ajaxview');
              }

              public function ajaxdata()
              {
                $message = $this->input->post('input_data');
                echo $message;
              }
```

View (ajaxview.php):

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search").keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    var post_data = {'input_data': val};
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
    $.ajax({ type :'POST', 
     data : post_data,
     url : base_url + "users/ajaxdata",
     success : function(data){
     $("#mydiv").html(data)
 }   
 });
 });
 });
</script>
```

```
<input type="text" id="search"></p>
<div id = "mydiv"></div>
```

I access the controller using http://www.example.com/index.php/users/ajaxform to get the form page.  However, when I type something into the form nothing appears and I can't figure out why. Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Please post the `users/ajaxview` and make a `console.log("something")` inside `$('#search').keyup()` function to see if event is executed, post the result here

Comment: Thanks.  I think I found the problem.  I did not have my routes.php file setup correctly.  When I added $route['users/ajaxdata'] = 'users/ajaxdata';  I get the correct behavior.

Comment: Fine glad you get the issue down